# Prove determinant equality

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I find myself in trouble with easy-looking linear algebra task.

Let $A, B, C, D$ be square $n\times n$ matrices such that $C\cdot D^T = D\cdot C^T$. Show that $\begin{vmatrix}A & B\\ C & D \end{vmatrix} = \vert A\cdot D^T - B\cdot C^T\vert$.

For square matrices we indeed have $\begin{vmatrix}A & B\\ C & D \end{vmatrix} = \vert AD - BC \vert$, but how to proceed further? I tried to plug $D = C D^T (C^T)^{-1}$ and $C = DC^T(D^T)^{-1}$ into this, but wasn't able to simplify it to desired form, although it seems the only straightforward way.

Comment: Did you try to show that $\mid AD-BC\mid=|A||D|-|B||C|$

Comment: @1ENİGMA1, no, I haven't, but if it will be done, the problem will be solved immediately, since transpose matrix has the same determinant with original one. How to do it with the given condition on matrices?

Comment: I will try my appropriate time.

Comment: Actually, we know that $det(A+B)\neq det(A)+det(B)$. For exapmle, let $A=I_n=B$. But, your question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 4, your equality is absolutely false, except when $A,B,C,D$ commute. Let $U=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}$.

Case 1. $A,D$ are invertible. Then $\det(U)=\det(A)\det(D-CA^{-1}B)$

cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

$\det(U)=\det(AD)\det(I-(D^{-1}C)A^{-1}B)$.  Here $D^{-1}C=C^TD^{-T}$.

$\det(U)=\det(AD^T)\det(I-C^T(D^{-T}A^{-1}B))=\det(AD^T)\det(I-(D^{-T}A^{-1}B)C^T)$.

Finally $\det(U)=\det(AD^T-BC^T)$.

Case 2. $A$ or $D$ is non-invertible. Proceed by continuity.

Comment: @Hasek , by politeness you could have written: "thanks my dog..."

Comment: Many thanks my dog =) I had very limited access to the Internet and MSE for a couple of previous weeks, take my apologizes for delayed acceptance of your answer.

Comment: @Hasek , OK, you have a sense of humour.